# replace underscores at end of name and numbers at beginning of name

Tags: regex, matlab, replace, simulink

i am still struggling with Matlab and regex.

This is what i got so far but it will just not work for me, no matter what i am trying..

set_param(blocks(i), 'Name', regexprep(get_param(blocks(i), 'Name'), '(_|[0-9])+', ''));

set_param(blocks(i), 'Name', regexprep(get_param(blocks(i), 'Name'), '_\w*', ''));

Any help is much appreciated!!

Error: You cannot set the name of '5Product' to an empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use alternation *and anchors*:

```
regexprep(str, '^[0-9]+|_+$', '')
```

The `^[0-9]+|_+$` pattern will match one of the two alternatives:

- `^[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits (`[0-9]+`) at the start of the string (`^`)
- `|` - or
- `_+$` - 1 or more `_` symbols (`_+`) at the end of the string (`$`)